# set_index of multiindex columns without using tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Setup**:

```
np.random.seed(0)
iix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bar', 'baz', 'foo'],['one', 'two']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6), columns=iix)

Out[120]:
        bar                 baz                 foo
        one       two       one       two       one       two
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
1  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
2  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158
```

To `set_index` on level = 1 and all columns `two`. I need to use a list of tuples as follows

```
df.set_index([('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'two'), ('foo', 'two')])

Out[121]:
                                       bar       baz       foo
                                       one       one       one
(bar, two) (baz, two) (foo, two)
 0.400157  2.240893   -0.977278   1.764052  0.978738  1.867558
-0.151357  0.410599    1.454274   0.950088 -0.103219  0.144044
 0.121675  0.333674   -0.205158   0.761038  0.443863  1.494079
```

**Question**: are there other simple ways to achieve this `set_index` without using the list of tuples as above?

*Note*: I know I can use list comprehension and `get_level_values` to generalize the construction of the list of tuples. However, I am interested in the way of using no list of tuples.

Comment: Is your expected out the same as what your are showing here?  MultiIndex with tuples?

Comment: @ScottBoston: yeah, I expect the index level names as tuples as in the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this bit of madness:

```
df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'two'])).loc(axis=1)[:,'one']
```

Output:

```
                                       bar       baz       foo
                                       one       one       one
(bar, two) (baz, two) (foo, two)                              
 0.400157  2.240893   -0.977278   1.764052  0.978738  1.867558
-0.151357  0.410599    1.454274   0.950088 -0.103219  0.144044
 0.121675  0.333674   -0.205158   0.761038  0.443863  1.494079
```

Using a little known parameter of `.loc`, `axis`. [See docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

> You can also specify the axis argument to .loc to interpret the passed
>   slicers on a single axis.